# Clone a specific git branch through Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, git-clone

I am facing difficulties to clone a specific git branch from Apple Xcode?

In Xcode -> Source Control -> Clone and insert my HTTP clone url and I can able clone only master branch but I did't find a solution to clone another developer branches from Xcode.

Through below command using terminal I can able to clone specific git branch.

**git clone -b my_dev_branch_name https://gitlab.com/Username/projectname_ios.git**

But I don't know how to do this using Xcode so please let me help to achieve this using Xcode.

Appreciated your great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can clone a specific branch from Xcode. However, after you cloned master, you can checkout any other branches from the remote using Xcode, then delete the local `master` if you don't want to store that locally.

Comment: You know how to do it with Terminal, so _do_ it with Terminal and move on. Xcode is a very poor git client; who cares what it can’t do? It can’t do most stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Ya, There is no option to select the branch when cloning project, But after clone you can change the branch.
Step in XCODE

> - Go to Xcode navigator (left side space in Xcode(ref:Image)) -> select the source control tab(2nd tab)
> - Select ProjectName->Remote->Origin->Branch name

[image: Change branch Image]