# Xcode 12.1 Source Control not showing all branches

Tags: xcode, git

In Xcode I can branch from master and push just fine. The new branch appears in Gitlab as one would expect.

When I use Xcode to clone the repo into a location, it asks me which branch to clone which seems fair. What I am confused about is that I can **only** see the cloned branch, not the other ones. If someone else (or I on another machine) create a branch, it won't update that addition on the other Xcode.

I know how to navigate branches via `git` in Terminal but then I don't understand why Xcode has the `Branches` entry to begin with. I can merge via Terminal but I thought the whole point of Xcode Source Control is to have a UI for visualizing conflicts etc.

Am I missing something or is this working normally for everyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54921527/2161301

When you expand `Remotes` and `origin` you will find the other branches too. So the "top level" `Branches` entry seems to be exclusively for local ones.

Comment: That actually makes sense, because remote-tracking names (`origin/master` and the like) aren't *branch* names. The Git terminology of calling them  "remote-tracking branch names" is, I think, just plain confusing. They *are* names, and they *are* remote-tracking, but they're not *branch* names.